# Yii Model has an invalid validation rule. Won't insert to multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I'm trying to create a user and I'm able to insert into my SystemUsers model and Parties model but now when I add code to try making an insert to my Persons model, I get the erros Persons has an invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name.

Is there anything wrong with my controller code?

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new SystemUsers;
        $modelParties = new Parties;
        $modelPersons = new Persons;
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($invoice);

if (isset($_POST['SystemUsers']))
    {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['SystemUsers']; 
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand("insert into parties (party_type_id) values ('1')")->execute();           
        $id = Yii::app()->db->lastInsertId; //The id from parties is a fk of system users

        $model->password = md5($model->password);//this works
        $model->party_id = $id; //this works
        $modelPersons->party_id = $id; //I believe errors start to occur startin here
        $modelPersons->email = $model->username;
        $modelPersons->save();



        if($model->save())
            echo "<script>alert('User Created');</script>";

//      }
        else $this->redirect(array('views22','id'=>$model->id));
 }

$this->render('create',array(
  'parties'=>$modelParties,
  'model'=>$model,
));
 }
```

These are the rules for my Persons model::

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('party_id, email, company_name, last_name, middle_name, gender, dob_year, dob_month, dob_day, nickname, language, address, country, location, moderator, from_date_location, to_date_location'),
        array('dob_year, dob_month, dob_day, language, country, location', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('party_id', 'length', 'max'=>20),
        array('email', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        array('company_name, last_name, middle_name, nickname', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('gender', 'length', 'max'=>6),
        array('sub_admin, moderator', 'length', 'max'=>1),
        array('image', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('party_id, email, company_name, last_name, middle_name, gender, image, dob_year, dob_month, dob_day, nickname, language, address, country, location, sub_admin, moderator, from_date_location, to_date_location', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rules function, you didn't mention rule for first array. You are just mentioning the field names without rule.

You have to mention `required` field validation rule as below

```
 array('party_id, email, company_name, last_name, middle_name, gender, dob_year, dob_month, dob_day, nickname, language, address, country, location, moderator, from_date_location, to_date_location','required'),
```